# Javascript regex unexpected output

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, node.js

I'm trying to use node to do some *regex* on a `css` file.

Here's my javascript:

```
var fs = require ('fs');

fs.readFile('test.css','utf8',function(error,css){
if(error){
    console.log("I'm sorry, something went terribly wrong :o Here's the message: "+error);
}



var matches = css.match(/([a-zA-Z-]+):\s*([0-9]+)(vh|VH|vw|VW)/g);

    console.log(matches[2][1]);



});
```

Expected output when I run it:

[image: regex101 output]

Actual output:
[image: actual output]

As you can see it does not put every match in its own array as expected, it just puts everything in one giant array without any sub-arrays.
Anything I can do?

Comment: Looks like an array to me...

Comment: Every match should be an array too, not a string

Comment: Match is working as intended. It ignores the capture groups if you are not specifically processing them. You either have to use a different method, or save the match capture groups in some loops.

Answer (score 1):

[`match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) doesn't give you the detailed match results in this case:

> If the regular expression includes the g flag, the method returns an Array containing all matched substrings rather than match objects.

You can use [`exec`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec) instead:

```
var regex = /([a-zA-Z-]+):\s*([0-9]+)(vh|VH|vw|VW)/g;
var css = "body{\nfont-size: 10vw;\n height: 500vh\n}";
var match;

while (match = r.exec(css)){
    console.log(match)
}
```

Which gives this output:

```
["font-size: 10vw", "font-size", "10", "vw", index: 6, input: "body{↵font-size: 10vw;↵ height: 500vh↵}"]  
["height: 500vh", "height", "500", "vh", index: 24, input: "body{↵font-size: 10vw;↵ height: 500vh↵}"]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var reg = /([a-zA-Z-]+):\s*([0-9]+)(vh|VH|vw|VW)/g;
var matches = [];
var m;

while ((m = reg.exec(css)) !== null) {
    if (m.index === reg.lastIndex) {
        reg.lastIndex++;
    }
    matches.push(m);
}

console.log(matches);
```

Answer (score 1):

It's actually expected behaviour. If you use `string.match` method with global flag, parenthesis do not create groups inside matches:

```
var str = "javascript is cool";
var result = str.match( /JAVA(SCRIPT)/g );
console.log( result[0] ); // javascript
console.log( result.length ); //1
```

Your case is using `regexp.exec(str)`. It can find all matches and parenthesis groups in it.

```
var str = 'javascript is cool. Use javascript';

var regexp = /java(script)/g;

while (result = regexp.exec(str)) {   
  console.log(result.length);   //2
  console.log(result[0]);  //javascript
  console.log(result[1]);  //script 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on above answers I managed to come up with the following code:

```
while(match = css.match(/([a-zA-Z-]+):\s*([0-9]+)(vh|VH|vw|VW)/)){
        matches.push(match);
        css = css.replace(match[0],'');
}
```

Thanks a ton for the help everyone!